# What is the type of index where multiple records share the same unique id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple versions of the same article. I want to make the look up faster. I think indexing will help. Is there a specific type of indexing that will work the best to get multiple records from the same table. My understanding is that index works by creating a sorted list and execute a binary search. But if multiple records have the same value then it'd just return the first one it finds not all of them.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy

Answer (score 1):

Have two tables - one with article metadata that doesn't change (indexed by article id) and one that has a compound index on article id and date with all date-specific data.

Even if all of your data was in one table (meaning that date-agnostic data is repeated) ten a compound index on article ID and date will make searches by article ID faster.

You shouldn't need to worry about specifics like binary searches - modern DBs will take of those details for you.

Comment: how does it work when indexed value is shared by multiple records? If thought through only binary search, then it'd return the first found. Does it do binary lookup and then searches for same values for along them in the sorted list.

Comment: Well ,"binary search" is an implementation detail, but basically the index is organized by the first value in the key, then the second. So if you have a compound index on X, Y and want to find all records for X, that's a fast search. If you then want a subset based on Y (say the "first" record for a days value), then that's another fast search.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong.  If you execute a query such as:

```
select h.*
from history h
where article_id = XXX
```

Then the query returns ALL articles for that `article_id`.  If you have an index on `history(article_id)` then the index will (probably) be used.  The index will be scanned for all matching articles.